# Minimizing the pain in Biceps and Shoulders due to Mountain Cycling or Offroad cycling

Tags: mountain-bike, fitness, off-road

I am a regular road cyclist, but I seldom go off the roads for cycling and Mountain Cycling. The terrain being damn rough and uneven, the jerks and the vibrations cause a lot of pain and numbness in Arms and Shoulders after a specific amount of endurance.

Have anybody tried a kind of a posture or may be skin-tight attire so that it is reduced? Or, how can I practice to endure such vibrations? This is rather a bit (or a lot) different than a regular exercise routine for strength building, isn't it?

EDIT: It doesn't have front and rear suspensions.

Comment: Are you using a road bike or mountain bike when going offroad? Does the bike have front or read suspension?  The make and model or the bike or a picture could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four factors I can think of

- bike
- tires
- riding style
- conditioning

If the bicycle has full suspension then less vibration.  Carbon frame will absorb vibration.    The fit of the bike is a huge factor.

Larger tires at lower pressure will absorb vibration.  Can run tubeless tires at lower pressure.   If you are running smaller tires then go to a bigger tire like 2.2 - 2.4 if your frame will allow.

Riding style has a lot to do with arm and shoulder fatigue. Try and relax. Move your body forward and back. Don't muscle the bars. Get in the middle and let the bike rock under you. Even if you can just learn to relax between the ruff sections you will gain a lot as the muscles get a chance to recover and get more blood flow.  Watch a good rider on ruff downhill - they are relaxed and a beginner will be tensed up fighting it the whole way.

The more you ride trails the more you will condition those muscles.  In the gym push up, pull up, fly, ...  Whatever is sore find the exercise that engages that muscle.

Comment: To add, I find it best to hold the grips with a lot of force, but leave the other parts of the hands relaxed. If the hold of the grip is loose, vibrations are more taxing to the fingers.